# Multiplicación y división dan 0 en lenguaje C

Tags: c

tengo un problema... estoy realizando una multiplicación y división en C pero me da 0, saben por qué o alguna forma de solucionarlo?
Estoy usando apuntadores...

```
double a, b, res;
REQUIERE_DATOS(&a, &b); //Se cargan los datos para 'a' y 'b'
MULTIPLICACION(a, b, &res); //Se realiza la multiplicación y se asigna a resultado
```

El problema está en la operación, ya intenté varias maneras y me sigue imprimiendo cero.
Realicé un `printf(PA*PB);` dentro de la función y da cero.

```
//FUNCIÓN MULTIPLICACION
void MULTIPLICACION (double PA, double PB, double *Pres){
    *Pres= PA*PB;
}
//FUNCIÓN DIVISION
void DIVISION (double PA, double PB, double *Pres){
    *Pres= PA/PB;
}
```

Comment: Tiene que ser `printf("%f", PA*PB)`.

Comment: Podrías poner la implementación de la función `REQUIERE_DATOS`. El código que has puesto no parece tener problemas

Answer (score 1):

En principio ese código está bien.
Aunque falta código, seguramente el problema lo tengas en como pasas los datos a esas funciones.

Como se quiere modificar el valor de la variable pasada como parámetro "Pres", la tenemos que pasar como referencia.
Te adjunto el código comentado para que lo veas bien.
Además, en este enlace se explica muy bien la diferencia entre las funciones por referencia (si queremos modificar los datos) o por valor (solo queremos mostrar los datos): https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/09/20/funciones-referencia-valor-c/

```
    #include <stdio.h>

//FUNCIÓN MULTIPLICACION
//FUNCIÓN MULTIPLICACION
void MULTIPLICACION (double PA, double PB, double *Pres){
    *Pres= PA*PB;
}
//FUNCIÓN DIVISION
void DIVISION (double PA, double PB, double *Pres){
    *Pres= PA/PB;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//creamos una variable donde guardar el resultado de la multiplicacion
double resultadoMulti;
//creamos una variable donde guardar el resultado de la division
double resultadoDivi;
    
    //Le pasamos a la función la dirección de memoria donde vamos a guardar el resultado
    // Es necesario pasarle la dirección de memoria (&) para poder modificarla dentro
    // de las funciones
    MULTIPLICACION(3.3,2.0, &resultadoMulti);
    printf("resultadoMulti= %f\n",resultadoMulti);
    DIVISION(6.4,2.0, &resultadoDivi);
    printf("resultadoDivi= %f\n",resultadoDivi);
    return 0;
}
```